# Kingfisher update from swift 2.3 to 3.0

Tags: xcode, swift3, kingfisher

I am suffering with a strange issue . I updated my project from 2.3 to swift 3.0 .Also updated my Kingfisher lib with the help of pod . But It it is giving following error "Module compiled with swift 3.0 can't be imported in swift 2.3". Please help..

Comment: Your complete project is not totally converted to swift 3,
Or you need to update your pod version